# Concatenate columns with same id Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-structures, jupyter-notebook

I have a DataFrame called weather with the following structure:

```
    STATION     DATE        ELEM    VALUE
0   US1MNCV0008 20170101    PRCP    0
1   US1MNCV0008 20170101    SNOW    0
2   US1MISW0005 20170101    PRCP    0
3   US1MISW0005 20170101    SNOW    0
4   US1MISW0005 20170101    SNWD    0
```

And I want to combine the rows using the date and the station to obtain the following:

```
    STATION     DATE        ELEM  VALUE ELEM  VALUE ELEM VALUE
0   US1MNCV0008 20170101    PRCP  0     SNOW  0
1   US1MISW0005 20170101    PRCP  0     SNOW  0     SNWD    0
```

I'm trying to achieve this by using:

```
weather.groupby(['station', as_index=False).agg(lambda x: x.tolist())
```

But this creates lists and is not what I want. How can I do the agregation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
df = (df.set_index(['STATION','DATE', df.groupby(['STATION','DATE']).cumcount()])
        .unstack()
        .sort_index(axis=1, level=1))
df.columns = ['{}_{}'.format(i, j) for i, j in df.columns]
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
       STATION      DATE ELEM_0  VALUE_0 ELEM_1  VALUE_1 ELEM_2  VALUE_2
0  US1MISW0005  20170101   PRCP      0.0   SNOW      0.0   SNWD      0.0
1  US1MNCV0008  20170101   PRCP      0.0   SNOW      0.0    NaN      NaN
```

**Explanation**:

1. Get count per groups by `STATION` and `DATE` with [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html)
2. Create `MultiIndex` by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)
3. Reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html)
4. Flatenning `MultiIndex` in columns
5. Convert `index` to columns by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

---

Or use [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) for create `DaatFrame` for each group, last solution same as above:

```
df = (df.groupby(['STATION','DATE'])['ELEM','VALUE']
       .apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x.values, columns=x.columns))
       .unstack()
       .sort_index(axis=1, level=1))
df.columns = ['{}_{}'.format(i, j) for i, j in df.columns]
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
       STATION      DATE ELEM_0 VALUE_0 ELEM_1 VALUE_1 ELEM_2 VALUE_2
0  US1MISW0005  20170101   PRCP       0   SNOW       0   SNWD       0
1  US1MNCV0008  20170101   PRCP       0   SNOW       0    NaN     NaN
```